# How can we prove that the tangent plane in a point of a surface in $R^3$ is indepent of the surface parameterisation

Tags: differential-geometry

For a surface in $R^3$, how can we show that the tangent plane is independent of how the surface is parameterised? I understand it intuitively, but cannot figure out how I would prove it rigorously.

Thanks

Comment: If you have two parametrizations, $\phi$ and $\psi$, of a common region in your surface, what must you assume about $\psi^{-1}\circ\phi$ as a mapping from an open set of $\Bbb R^2$ to another open set of $\Bbb R^2$?